# include graphics with path from external USB drive

Tags: graphics

Can LaTeX include graphics/images in `pdf` if I write the path from external USB drive?
I notice that it includes images if I write path from the SSD directory but not from my external USB drive.
I use the following packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,left=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
```

I use TexShop 3.61 on a MacBook Pro Retina OS X El Capitan 10.11.3
I searched the net but could not find an answer so far. My brain is getting tired.
Thanks for any help you can provide
Luís
[image]

Comment: While this is a bit difficult to diagnose from afar I would guess this has nothing to do whether the files are on the USB drive or the SSD. LaTeX might have difficulties though with the special characters and spaces in the path to the files. These differ in your example between the two figure files.

Comment: It is unlikely to be related to the disk type. I note that the typeset file path in your top image has dropped the accented u and shows `Sade`  so most likely tex isn't understanding the character encoding used in filenames

Comment: Hi, this funny thing happened, I got the answer to my question just by reviewing the image I included in my question!!!! I found out what was the problem: the acute accent in the path (Saúde). I changed the folder to “Saude” and voilá, problem solved. I thought I was going to have a brain drain after several hours searching for the solution to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle didn't the quotation marks indicate that special characters are used in the file name? or are only spaces caught in the process?

Comment: @naphaneal only spaces (and anyway it's not enough to know the characters are not ascii you need to know how they are encoded, not all filesystems use utf8, I have no idea what a mac formatted usb stick uses:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As far as I know, USB formatting is universal, unlike standard external drives; there isn't a specific Mac format.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely to be related to the disk type. I note that the typeset file path in your top image has dropped the accented u and shows Sade so most likely tex isn't understanding the character encoding used in filenames.